# Mongodb | mongoose: Remove from nested document with $pull

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following two models:

**Capture**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var captureSchema = Schema({
    type: String,
    birdname: {type: String, required: true},
    place: String,
    note: String,
    userId: String,
    author: String,
    picture: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    created_at: Date,
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Capture', captureSchema);
```

**Comment**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var commentSchema = Schema({
    body: String,
    userId: String,
    author: String,
    created_at: Date,
    capture: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Capture'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

My goal is to remove a comment from a capture but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the ref 'id' from capture once I have deleted a comment.

Currently I'm using the following the remove a comment:

```
var Comment = require('../models/comment');
var Capture = require('../models/capture');

...

router.delete('/comments/:id', function(req, res){
         Comment.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err){
             res.json({result: err ? 'error' : 'ok'});
             console.log('comment removed');
         });

           //DOES NOT WORK ---> Need assistance with $pull
            Capture.update({_id: Capture.comments._id}, {
             $pull : {'comments' : req.params.id}}, function(err, data) {
                if(err) throw err;
                res.json(
         });
     });
```

But for some reason, only my comment gets deleted, but the reference stays on my capture as followed (example):

```
{
    "_id": "574b640e39c34ad806b7eab6",
    "created_at": "2016-05-29T21:50:06.772Z",
    "picture": "https://cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/C9Z73CQwCiFP8pdB5W7A",
    "author": "Cedric Bongaerts",
    "userId": "facebook|10153403872376529",
    "place": "Afrika",
    "birdname": "Mountain Serpent Eagle",
    "type": "ok",
    "__v": 14,
    "comments": [
                "574cbfa6ab7e2b44184584df",
                "574cbfa6ab7e2b4682452fss",
                "574cb61vdz422b57584d417s",
                ]
}
```

While my comments are empty (been deleted).

**Edit:**
An extra thing to mention:
When I get the capture by 'id' `/api/captures/:capture`, it does show that the comment is deleted.. It only stays when viewing the full captures list `/api/captures`

Comment: Your `{_id: Capture.comments._id}` parameter to the `Comment.remove` call doesn't seem to make much sense. That should be using the _id of the Capture document to update.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I realise that. Though I tried Comment.capture._id but it gives undefined. I can't seem to get the capture id.

Comment: @JohnnyHK In other words, where I'm struggling, is getting the id of the capture, so that I can edit it (I've got the vote Id through the param)

Comment: Why is `capture` an array in `commentSchema`? Can a comment really be linked to more than one capture?

Comment: Not really, good point. Though that doesn't solve the problem. when removing the ` [ ] ` from the comment model as such `capture: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Capture'}`, I still can't get the capture for some reason..

Comment: @JohnnyHK using `Comment.capture` gives undefined

Comment: `Comment` is the model definition, not the comment being removed. I posted an answer to show how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the comment document you're removing so that you can access its `capture` field that contains the `_id` of the `Capture` document to remove the comment reference from. The easiest way to do that is to use [`findByIdAndRemove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) instead of just `remove` when removing the comment:

```
Comment.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, comment){
    if (comment) {
        Capture.update({_id: comment.capture}, {
                $pull : {comments: req.params.id}
            }, function(err, data) { ... });
    }
});
```

Note that this assumes that `capture` is not an array (as discussed in the comments), and is defined like this instead:

```
capture: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Capture'}
```

Comment: Sounds so simple when you say it like that. Thanks for the help.